# Python ploty graph for time series RTTM file

Tags: matplotlib, time-series, timeserieschart

I have this panda dataframe:

```
0 music 0.00 9.02 
1 female 9.02 152.70 
2 music 152.70 155.12 
3 female 155.12 206.82 
4 noEnergy 206.82 208.10
```

basically an ID, TYPE, START, END
All this event are in sequence, so they cannot overlap.
My goal is to obtain a graph to show it sequence for the event duration, like
this:
[image]

Basically I want to "interpolate" the "music" type from 0 to 9.02, "female" to 9.02 to 152.70, and so on.

using this code:

```
    # Read data from RTTM files into data frames
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
    df1 = pd.read_csv('file.rttm', sep=' ', names=['type', 'start', 'end'])
    df1.plot(x='start', y='type', kind='scatter', rot='vertical')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

This only show the start position in time.

If I plot using this:

```
df1['duration'] = (df1['end'] - df1['start'])
plt.plot(df1['start'], df1['type'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

That once again is not what I would like to visualize.
Any suggestion on right way to visualize it? Thx

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your use of "interpolate". From the screenshot and what you've tried, I feel like you're trying to display each entry as a horizontal segment from START value to END value, on the correct Y level depending on the type. Is it correct?

Comment: you are absolutely correcy @thmslmr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you're trying to display each dataframe entry as a horizontal segment from START value to END value, on the correct Y level depending on the type. Here is a solution using `matplotlib`.

First, here is a sample of the fake data I've created (and used) based on the short sample you provided.

|  | START | END | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 726 | 728 | music |
| 6 | 195 | 214 | music |
| 15 | 453 | 464 | female |
| 47 | 1478 | 1506 | noEnergy |
| 9 | 304 | 318 | female |
| 20 | 599 | 610 | female |
| 23 | 738 | 747 | music |
| 6 | 219 | 237 | female |
| 31 | 947 | 954 | music |
| 17 | 570 | 595 | noEnergy |

The solution uses the fact that you can plot a batch of segments at once using the following `plt.plot` signature ([see here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)):

```
plot([x], y, [fmt], [x2], y2, [fmt2], ..., **kwargs)
```

So, for each type, we want to create a list of `X, Y` (`[START value, END value]`, `[Y_type, Y_type]`) and unpack everything in the `plt.plot` function. This will plot all the segments for a given TYPE.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))

dfgroups = df.groupby("TYPE")

for i, (gtype, group) in enumerate(dfgroups):

    segments_data = np.full((len(group), 2, 2), i)
    segments_data[:, 0, :] = group[["START", "END"]]
    segments_data = segments_data.reshape((-1, 2))

    plt.plot(*segments_data, marker="|", c="k")
    
plt.yticks(range(dfgroups.ngroups), dfgroups.groups.keys())
```

Here is the result on my fake test data:

[image]